# How to update custom field in product variations and delete product variation by title content?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, product-variations

1) I am seeking a way how to update a custom field in product variations. something like:

```
update_post_meta($variation, 'cron_function_security_field','this_variation_will_be_kicked_out');
```

OR

```
wp_update_post(array(
        'ID'    =>  $variation->ID,
        'cron_function_security_field'   =>  'this_variation_will_be_kicked_out'
    ));.
```

Any ideas?

2) Just like above, would there be a way to delete a product variation after it has been identified via title content?

```
private function trash_unwanted_variations() {

    $variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation->ID);

    $variationName = the_title($variation->ID);
    $variationName_slug = sanitize_title($variationName);
    $variationName_dash = sanitize_title_with_dashes($variationName);

    if (strpos($variationName_slug,'latka')!==false && strpos($variationName_dash,'cena-za-1-bezny-metr')!==false) {
        $this->wp_delete_post($variation, true);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to put together something like this?